# How to unit test in XCTest auto layout exceptions that are dynamic?

Tags: ios, autolayout, xctest, lldb

When a test is running and it detects an auto layout exception it should fail it. What I don't want to do is assert against a specific value. For example I don't want to do this: `XCTAssertEqual(view.bounds.height, 200.0)`

Comment: I think it's possible to do with with LLDB, but I'm just wondering how to attach a process during your tests run.

Comment: If you are running your tests under Xcode, then by default Xcode will run them under the debugger (there's a checkbox in the Test Scheme to turn this on and off.)  But I don't know how auto-layout exceptions are delivered.  It doesn't sound like something that automatically causes your test to stop in lldb - or you would have already seen it stop...